# How to assign a numbering scheme to TreeNodes based on it's position in treeview

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a TreeView control in a Windows Forms application that is displaying my own subclass of TreeNode. I need to display a number along with each nodes' text indicating its position in the tree, like 1 for the root, 1.1 for its first child, 1.2 for its second child, etc. I'm using C#

Comment: You can use `TreeNode.Depth` to figure out how many 'dots' to use, and `TreeNode.Nodes.IndexOf` on the parent to figure out where the current node is.

Comment: You need to document this question better.  Post your relevant TreeNode subclass code.